# Mensagem no "print" não é impressa na tela, como corrigir?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A mensagem de `print` não aparece na tela, será que tem relação com a variável?

```
cp = str
input("seu nome")
if(cp)=='jefferson': print('JFP')
```

Comment: Esse código não faz sentido, o que deseja fazer?

Comment: resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

É mais simples que isto.

```
if input("seu nome") == "jefferson": print("JFP")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bmoLKu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/chdauojw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/InputIf.py).

Tem um motivo para criar uma variável? Se não tem não crie. Na verdade não coloque nada do código se não puder justificá-lo.

Imagino que queria converter o que foi digitado para *string*. Mas pra que, se o que foi digitado já é uma *string*? E está com sintaxe incompleta em linhas separadas. Sugiro entender melhor como funciona a sintaxe básica das coisas, qual a função de cada parte do código, porque está usando cada caractere. Sem entender essas coisas você nunca poderá programar com destreza.

Comment: vish cara, desculpa pela ignorância, eu tava estudando, fui parar esqueci tudo, obrigado, eu que achei que iria funcionar desse jeito q postei

Comment: Não há necessidade de falar assim com o rapaz, se ele é leigo ou novato, não justifica sua atitude, por favor edite sua resposta para uma forma mais sensata.

Comment: @RenanOsorio você quer que ele nunca aprenda? Me desculpe, mas eu não penso como você. Eu estou aqui pra ajudar as pessoas evoluírem. A sua atitude faz com que as pessoas fiquem sempre na mesma. Eu não estou mal tratando ninguém, estou orientando o que deve fazer para melhorar. E gosto de fazer isto e as pessoas que seguem a orientação acabam se tornando profissionais. As pessoas que que não gostam disto acabam não indo pra frente. Eu lamento que você prefira que seja assim.

Comment: Hoje a maioria das pessoas sequer entendem o que precisam para evoluir, e a culpa disso é ter um monte de gente passando a mão na cabeça e falando que está tudo certo sem que esteja. Novamente, me desculpe se você não gosta, mas a resposta não tem nada de errado, não está errada e não merece negativo porque você não gostou do texto. Você está fazendo mais mal do que o que está reclamando porque o voto não é para avaliar a resposta e sim represália porque não gostou do texto. Isso não é legal. E mais estranho ainda vir 2 votos assim. Vou chamar outro mod para analisar o q está acontecendo aqui

Comment: eu não acho que a resposta do @Maniero foi ofensiva nesse caso - pode ser chamada de dura e direta, mas está bem dentro dos limites de cordialidade (com o uso do verbo 'sugiro' e etc...).  E são pontos reais, que alguns dos usuários iniciantes por aqui podem achar que são secundários, quando não são.

Comment: @jsbueno sim, eu sou duro e direto, sei que alguns não gostam disto, mas eu prefiro assim, e acho que faço mais bem que mal. Não querendo me comparar ao Steve Jobs (eu sou muito melhor :D zuei) "Meu trabalho não é pegar leve com as pessoas. Meu trabalho é torná-las melhores". Nunca foi tão preciso mostrar que as pessoas precisam seguir outros caminhos. A proporção dos que estão trilhando caminhos tortuosos é muito grande. Discordar, pressionar sempre, ofender jamais. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu só não gosto quando você fecha umas questões genéricas que eu ia conseguir contextualizar e responder! :-)

Comment: @jsbueno edita ela pra salvar ;)